# Looking Firestore Query to Fetch Chat IDs for a User

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on implementing a chat feature using Firestore, and I am facing a challenge in constructing a query to retrieve all chat IDs associated with a specific user.

Here is a brief overview of my Firestore structure:

```
"chats" (collection)
   |
   └── chat_id (document)
         |
         └── "messages" (collection)
               |
               └── message_id (document)
                     |
                     ├── senderId
                     └── receiverId
```

In this structure, a user can be either a sender or a receiver in a chat. I am looking for a query that can fetch all chat IDs where a given user (identified by their user ID) is either the sender or the receiver.

For example, let's say the user ID is "f185a6fa-1d76-4ebb-97f9-eec7a205b13b." This user ID may exist in either the "senderId" or "receiverId" field within the "messages" collection.

I would be grateful if anyone could provide a Firestore query that accomplishes this task efficiently. Additionally, any explanations or insights into the query's functionality would be highly beneficial for my understanding.

Comment: Perhaps this [resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ywu7_vfU9HM) will help you find a way to structure a Firestore database for a chat app.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a great use-case for adding an [OR condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries) to a query:

```
const q = query(messagesRef,  
  or(where('senderId', '==', "f185a6fa-1d76-4ebb-97f9-eec7a205b13b"),
     where('receiverId', '==', "f185a6fa-1d76-4ebb-97f9-eec7a205b13b")
  )
);
```

---

Beyond that, I'd typically recommend adding an array field with the UIDs of the participants to the messages documents too:

```
participantUIDs: ["f185a6fa-1d76-4ebb-97f9-eec7a205b13b", "otherUID"]
```

This gives you another option to get the messages that the UID participates in as you can use an [array membership condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership):

```
const q = query(messagesRef, where("participantUIDs", "array-contains", "f185a6fa-1d76-4ebb-97f9-eec7a205b13b"));
```

Either of these approaches will work, and neither is pertinently better than the other, so it's good to know of both options so you can decide what is easiest for your current each use-case.